# how to change wrap_width in SublimeText-Markdown?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

SublimeText-Markdown is a plug-in for SublimeText text editor. It's default configuration has a word-wrap set to 80 characters.

The plug-in can be configured with `MultiMarkdown.sublime-settings - User`.

My settings are as follows:

```
{
    "wrap_width": 100
}
```

The word-wrap continues at 80 character.

Question:

How can I change the word-wrap in markdown using SublimeText-Markdown in SublimeText 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Menu path:

**View -> Word Wrap Column -> 100**